# Why does Kotlin Result catch Throwables?

Tags: kotlin

In Java it was considered a bad practice to catch and handle Throwables, because they include unrecoverable Errors. However, runCatching and mapCatching from Kotlin standard library do catch them and wrap them in a Result like any other exception. Is it generally OK to catch Throwables in Kotlin or is Result a special case (and if so, why)?

Comment: I think it's just Kotlin stdlib developers' design choice. You can rethrow on failure if this is not the way you want, which is simpler than *enclosing again if you want to catch all `Throwables` when the stdlib does not catch them*. Maybe this can be helpful: https://medium.com/@mattia23r/a-take-on-functional-error-handling-in-kotlin-515b67b4212b

Comment: This is a great question which I would love to have an answer to. It's one of the least intuitive things I've encountered in Kotlin. When you factor in the fact that `runCatching` is a building block in other APIs like coroutines, this causes me trouble almost on a daily basis.

Comment: Here's the lead designer of Kotlin on this topic: https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07 Basically, the idea is that you only catch recoverable errors like IOExceptions, and you do it in low-level helper functions that wrap the result so your general code is never catching anything. In that case `runCatching`'s primary purpose would be for composing these low level helper functions.

Comment: I think they have more planned in this area, since you're currently forbidden from returning the stdlib Result class. They want to do some sort of syntax thing to improve it before releasing this restriction.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found [a series of tweets](https://twitter.com/relizarov/status/1299248297849303040) about this topic by Roman Elizarov, Team Lead in Kotlin Language Research:

> If you need error logging/handling (usually at the top level), catch
> `Throwable`. [...] In fact `catch(e: Exception)` [is a bad practice]. You either
> catch an operation-specific exception you need to handle (e.g.
> `IOException`) or all of them (which means `Throwable`). I've never seen a
> real reason to have `catch(e: Exception)` in your code. It is a bug
> waiting to hit you.

on distinction between unrecoverable Errors and recoverable Exceptions:

> Java wanted to make this distinction in 1996 but failed to adhere to
> it when the platform grew and scaled. In fact, nowadays it is never
> possible, in practice, to tell if the problem is recoverable by its
> class. The distinction in the JVM and the whole naming confusion is
> just a 25-year-old legacy of the bygone era. No one could have
> actually predicted back then how it all works out in big systems.

on what to do with Errors:

> Log it, notify support, restart the affected operation/subsystem, etc.
> No reason limiting those actions just to `Exception` subtypes. I've
> virtually never had issues with logging or otherwise handling
> `OutOfMemoryError`, `StackOverflowError`, `AssertionError`, and others
> (barring fatal bugs in JVM which are rare). The fact [that] they were
> properly handled in code saved countless hours of support efforts
> later. In practice [...] OOMs are often caused by bugs in the code
> that is trying to allocate some very big data structures. When this
> code crashes with OOM the GC cleans up the memory which lets, at
> least, your error-handling code to log it properly.